# The database reported a syntax error: Duplicate column name 'Product_Number'

Tags: mysql, domo

It says that The database reported a syntax error:

> Duplicate column name 'Product_Number'.

Below is the code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `df_all_orders_merged_la` 
LEFT JOIN `product_database_la` 
    ON `df_all_orders_merged_la`.`Product_Number` = `product_database_la`.`Product_Number`
WHERE `product_database_la`.`Product_Number` IS NULL;
```

Comment: Try to select exactly field what you need instead `*`. For example `SELECT df_all_orders_merged_la.*`

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev You tell "exactly field" and nevertheless use asterisk. ???

Answer (score 1):

If both `df_all_orders_merged_la` and `product_database_la` contain a column named `product_number` you will get this error.

What you need to do is to *disambiguate* your request by using table aliases such as the letters `p` and `m` in this rewritten query:

```
 SELECT m.* 
 FROM `df_all_orders_merged_la` m
   LEFT JOIN `product_database_la` p
ON m.`Product_Number` = p.`Product_Number`
WHERE p.`Product_Number` IS NULL;
```

Here I have used the letters `p` and `m` to refer to particular tables in the `FROM` and `JOIN` section.  Also notice what I did to the `SELECT` clause:  I'm no longer pulling in anything from table `p`.  (But I did this only to get rid of the immediate ambiguity ...)

> In general, I recommend that you *specify* the fields that you actually need in your result, rather than relying on the `SELECT *` crutch in any of its many forms.  *Document,* in the query, exactly what columns you really need, and which tables they come from:

```
 SELECT m.order_id, p.product_number, p.product_name [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are joining the table and a new temporary table is formed on the basis of Product_Number column in the both parent table so in new table two duplicate column will be formed.

Now since you are calling select * from ... , due to * in select query mysql doesn't know which particular Product_Number column you want to select as having two same name column in this new table is ambigious to it without any specification(like Product_Name of which parent table you want to see) because astrick(*) replace * in query with all the column names in the specified table(without specifying any parent table and it becomes sometimes problematic in case of joins when there is/are column name having same name but different parent tables).

Think about if you are calling just by column name, how does mysql will know which parent table column it should show as there name can be same but there is possibility that content can be different or in just different order and it can't possibly know in this way which particular type column you want. maybe it shows you some random column among duplicates but you wanted some other column having same name!

so the way to select in this type of cases is by specifying the name of all the unique column just by column name(you can specify parent table too but it doesn't matter) without specifying parent table and for duplicate column you will have to call like

```
select `df_all_orders_merged_la`.`Product_Number,`product_database_la`.`Product_Number` from (... your join query here ...);
```

i.e specify the parent table of the column from which you want to show like above, again you can give alias to parent tables for your convenience